# How do i save a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok so im making a test and i am trying to save the way the page looks after a user has taken the test so that way they can access it on a server side table to review its answers. I have looked and have not really found a way to do this.  The idea is after the user has submitted the test it will show right and wrong answers, save, then that page is sent to the table.  Any help is appreciated.

In case anyone is curious here is my code :

```
function finishTest(){
//There are actually 37 questions on the test so far only included 3
var score = 0;
var totalQuestions = 37;


for(var questionNum = 1; questionNum<=totalQuestions; questionNum++) {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('q'+questionNum);
var uQuestion = document.getElementById("question "+questionNum).innerHTML;
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value=="1"){

        score++;
        alert(radios.innerHTML);
        radios[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "lawngreen";

        }else if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value=="0"){


        alert(radios.innerHTML);
       radios[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "orangered";


        }
}
}

score = parseFloat(score*100/totalQuestions).toFixed(1);
alert("You scored "+score+"%");

document.getElementById('finish').style.visibility='hidden';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lwalden answered, it is generally the right idea to save save the user's input and repopulate the document with those values later, rather than saving and restoring the entire document. That's a basic part of working with forms and user input.

Just for some fun and to directly answer your question, here is a basic example. Again, this is not the proper way to approach your project.

[**Live demo here.**](http://jsbin.com/puvuyo/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="type here...">
    <button id="save-btn">Click here to save.</button>
  </div>
  <h1>Saved doc:</h1>
  <iframe id="saved-doc"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById('save-btn');
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get value of inputs and add them to the actual elements
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(input) {
    input.setAttribute('value', input.value);
  });
  // get the document as a string
  var doc = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  save(doc);
});

// save it however you want, probably ajax request to a server
// in this example, I'm saving it to localStorage
function save(doc) {
  localStorage.doc = doc;
  loadSavedDoc();
}

// loading the saved doc into an iframe
function loadSavedDoc() {
  var savedDoc = document.getElementById('saved-doc');
  savedDoc.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML = localStorage.doc;
}
loadSavedDoc();
```

Replying to your comment, this sample code is to help you get the idea of saving and restoring user input. In a real project, you'd probably want named input fields in forms, to save to an object, and a library/framework to keep the code minimal and clean.

[**Live demo here.**](http://jsbin.com/tologe/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button id="save-btn">Save</button>
<button id="load-btn">Load</button>
```

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById('save-btn');
var loadBtn = document.getElementById('load-btn');
var textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var vals = [];
  [].forEach.call(textInputs, function(input) {
    vals.push(input.value);
  });
  localStorage.vals = JSON.stringify(vals);
});
loadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  JSON.parse(localStorage.vals).forEach(function(val, idx) {
    textInputs[idx].value = val;
  });
});
```

Comment: So in the sense i save everything the way the user has done everything to an object, then call that object through a duplicate page?

Comment: @TheNamesZero Check out my updated answer, new code and demo. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving the html page, you would want to capture all the variables - test answer, score, userName?, etc, that you want to save in an object and send that object to your server.

Then you can create a review page that when rendered asks the server for those details and displays them.

Exactly how to send the data to the server really depends on what how your server and database are set up.